# XSS on <script src=""

Tags: xss

I'm trying to solve @kinugawamasato xss challenge

https://vulnerabledoma.in/xss_2020-06/

It's a php script that receives a argument, escapes it and create he following tag on the html:

```
<script src="/xss_2020-06/check_code.php?callback=callback&amp;code=PARAM"></script>
```

So `PARAM` is the argument. The maximum payload is 10 chars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a platform to solve CTF excercises.
Still I had a look and will give you a hint:

When requesting `check_code.php?callback=callback&code=PARAM` you pass two arguments.

Your result is `callback("Invalid code: 'PARAM'")`.
Don't focus too much on the `code` parameter.

It's a very easy CTF task